# Flux of vector field through a cylinder

Tags: calculus, vector-fields, cylindrical-coordinates

Problem is to find the flow of vector field:
$$\vec F=x^2\widehat i+y^2\widehat j+z^2\widehat k$$
through the outer side of a cylindrical surface $x^2+y^2=4$, bounded by planes $z=0$ and $z=8$, but we are only calculating the flux in the cylinder, not through the top and bottom planes.

I have tried using the normal and parameterise the cylinder and use the expression $$\iint\vec F\cdot\widehat n \:dS$$ but I can't get it right. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cylindrical coordinates to parametrize the cylindrical surface 
$$
\vec{r}(\theta,z)=\langle 2 \cos \theta, 2\sin \theta,z\rangle, 
\hspace{2mm} 
\mbox{ where } 
\hspace{2mm} 0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi 
\hspace{2mm}
\mbox{ and }
\hspace{2mm} 0\leq z \leq 8. 
$$
So the vector field $\vec{F}$ is given by 
$$
\vec{F} = \langle 4\cos^2 \theta, 4\sin^2\theta,z^2 \rangle,  
$$
and the normal vector $\vec{N}$ is 
$$
\vec{N} = \vec{r}_{\theta} \times \vec{r}_z = 
\left|
\begin{pmatrix}
\widehat{i} & \widehat{j} & \widehat{k} \\
-2\sin \theta & 2\cos \theta & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\right| 
= \langle 2\cos\theta, 2\sin\theta,0\rangle,  
$$
where $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$, $0\leq z\leq 8$, and 
$\widehat{i}, \widehat{j}, \widehat{k}$ are the standard unit vectors. 
Since we want the normal vector to have unit length, 
$$
\widehat{n} = \frac{\vec{N}}{||\vec{N}||} = \langle \cos\theta, \sin\theta, 0 \rangle. 
$$ 
Thus the flux is 
$$
\begin{align*}
\text{Flux} 
&= \int\int_S \vec{F}\circ \widehat{n}\: dS \\ 
&= \int_{0}^{8} \int_{0}^{2\pi} 
  \langle 4\cos^2 \theta, 4\sin^2\theta,z^2 \rangle \circ 
  \langle \cos\theta, \sin\theta, 0 \rangle \: d\theta \: dz  \\ 
&= 8 \int_{0}^{2\pi} 4 (\cos^3 \theta+ \sin^3\theta)\: d\theta 
= \boxed{0}. 
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Try the parametrization

\begin{align*}
x(u,v)&=2\cos(v),\\
y(u,v)&=2\sin(v),\\
z(u,v)&=u,\\
\text{where}&\\
0&\leq u\leq 8,\,\,\, 0\leq v\leq 2\pi.
\end{align*}
Note that $\vec{r}(u,v)=x(u,v)\vec{i}+y(u,v)\vec{j}+z(u,v)\vec{k}$, is a vector that points to a point on the surface. You can use
\begin{align*}
\vec{n}\mathrm{d}S&=\vec{r}_{u}\times\vec{r}_{v}\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v
\end{align*}

The trick is now to substitute for $x,y,z$ the expressions in terms of $u,v$ into $\vec{F}$. Then integrate

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{8}\vec{F}\cdot\left(\vec{r}_{u}\times\vec{r}_{v}\right)\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v
\end{align*}